# Ajax variable not displaying on response

Tags: php, html, ajax, arrays, json

I am trying to incorporate some ajax into my code, at the moment it works great, when a user clicks a button it sends some hidden inputs to another php script, performs some actions, then sends the result back and outputs it, all updating with no refresh etc.

However, the last part I am trying to send and receive back is a variable that shows some html code, in other words the other variables that are being sent back and outputed are just numbers and letters, where as this one is actual div's, however it is not outputting it, I have tried it without the ajax, when the page first loads and it works great, but doesn't when i try it with the ajax, hopefully the code below will make more sense. The variable I want to be able to send back is `$sl_output`.

AJAX code on main page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){ 

    $(".add_detail_land_down").click(function(){

        var hidden_count = $('input[name=addon_detail_hidden_count]').val();
        var land_required = $('input[name=addon_hidden_land_required]').val();
        var sl_array = $('input[name=addon_hidden_shopping_list_array]').val();
        var button_tok = "land_down";

     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "addon_detail_calc.php",
            data: { hidden_count: hidden_count, button_tok: button_tok, land_required: land_required, sl_array: sl_array  },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
    $("#res_expected_gain").html(data.total_hidden);
    $("#output").html(data.output);
    $("#res_expected_profit").html(data.land_required);
    $("#res_total_supply_time").html(data.test_time);
    $("#land_selected_token").html(data.total_hidden);
    $("#sl_output_div").html(data.sl_output);
}
        });
        return false;
})

});
```

Code in `addon_detail_calc.php`

```
    <?php 
// header('application/json');
$hidden_count = $_GET["hidden_count"];
$button_tok = $_GET["button_tok"];
$land_required = $_GET["land_required"];
$sl_array = $_GET["sl_array"];
$sl_output = "";
if($button_tok == "land_up"){

    //MAIN CODE SHALL BE DONE HERE
    $hidden_count = $hidden_count + 1;
    $test_time = $hidden_count * 66;


    $new_sl_array = array();
$final_sl_array = array();
foreach ($sl_array as $columnName => $columnData) {

        if($columnName == "0"){
            unset($sl_array[$columnName]);

        }else{

            $new_columnData = $columnData * 54;
            $new_sl_array[$columnName] = $new_columnData;

        }

    }
foreach ($new_sl_array as $columnName => $columnData) {

            $sl_output = "";
            $sl_output = '<li class="add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele"><div class="add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_header">'.$columnName.'</div><!--end add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_header--><div class="add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_pic"></div><!--end add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_pic--><div class="add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_amount">47 Required</div><!--end add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_amount--><div class="add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_user_amount">You Have 0</div><!--end add_detail_content_ele_wrap_ele_user_amount--></li>';

            $final_sl_array[$columnName] = $sl_output;

        }

$array_result = implode("", $final_sl_array);

    }else{        
        $hidden_count = $hidden_count;  

}else{

    $hidden_count = $hidden_count;  

}


$output = "";
$output = '<input type="hidden" name="addon_detail_hidden_count" id="addon_detail_hidden_count" class="addon_detail_hidden_count" value="'.$hidden_count.'" />';
include 'connect_to_mysql.php';

echo json_encode(array("total_hidden" => $hidden_count, "output" => $output, "land_required" => $hidden_count, "test_time" => $test_time, "sl_output" => $final_sl_array ));

 ?>
```

I guess the question is, can the html code variable being transported be viewed and re-outputed?

### EDIT

I have updated my code above, it seems that the first problem, was the foreach loop wasn't handling the right data, i had to shuffle things around and add another array. Because of this i have to put every value in array `final_sl_array` into a single variable, i have tried to implode this, it worked when i ran it through normal php when the page opens, however, now when i try it through ajax, it is not working, and not returning any result, any ideas why it works for one and not the other?

Comment: Did you use firebug / chrome dev tools to verify that the json coming back is what you expect?  Also those tools can help you view the dom - i.e. see if the dom has the html, but maybe CSS is hiding it or something

Comment: Hi, okay i just checked, and it shows that it is not sending anything back, here is a snippet from it `"land_required":2,"test_time":132,"sl_output":"` You can see that land_required and test_time send back the right results, but sl_output which is what i want is not sending back anything, what do you think could be causing this? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Hi, i have managed to figure out, that it works as long as the $sl_output is not inside that foreach, not sure why though?

Comment: In your current code, you implode `$final_sl_array` into a string stored in a var named `$array_result` but you never output that string. Instead, you include the array `$final_sl_array` in the JSON encoded output.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i do include array_result instead of final_sl_array in the JSON, but i was doing some tests, and copied the wrong code :/ Sorry

Comment: I think i have just figured it out anyway, apparently you can't send an array via ajax to the external php script, the array in question is sl_array